# Webview Supported Characters?

Tags: android, webview, character

Is there a list of supported characters in a `WebView`? I'm talking about special characters and I want to know if there are some unsupported characters. In `TextViews` there are for example `BulletPoints` unsupported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have any idea regarding How many character is not supported by `WebView` but when some character is not supported in `WebView` then convert that Symbol into its respective `HTML Codes` it will work for you...

[This link](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) might help you.

Comment: so if I use HTML all html-special-characters will be supported, right?